# Numpy fastest 3D to 2D projection

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I have a 3D array of binary data. I want to project this to 3 2D images - side on, head on, birds eye.

I have written the code:

```
for x in range(data.shape[2]):
    for y in range(data.shape[0]):
        val = 0
        for z in range(data.shape[1]):
            if data[y][z][x] > 0:
                val = 255
                break
        side[y][x] = val
```

But this is horrifically slow (75s!) for a ~700x300x300 matrix.

What is the fastest way of achieving this task?

EDIT:

To save the image, I have used:

```
sideImage = Image.fromarray(side)
sideImage.convert('RGB').save("sideImage.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute it as follows:

```
>>> data = np.random.random_sample((200, 300, 100)) > 0.5
>>> data.any(axis=-1).shape # show the result has the shape we want
(200, 300)
>>> data.any(axis=-1)
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ...,
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

You can scale values if you need

```
>>> data.any(axis=-1) * 255
array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]])
>>>
```

Comment: That seems to work great, is there a way I can save the image? I have added my old code to the original post

Comment: I recommend [`imsave` from scikit image](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/packages/scikit-image/index.html#input-output-data-types-and-colorspaces) or otherwise `imsave` from `scipy.misc`

Answer (score 6):

When I have 3D data, I tend to think of it as a 'cube' with rows, columns, and slices - or panels, of 2D images. Each slice or panel is a 2D image that is of dimensions `(rows, cols)`. I usually think of it like this:

[image: 3D data cube]

with `(0,0,0)` being in the upper left corner of the **front** slice. With `numpy` indexing it is super easy to select just the portions of the 3D array that you are interested in *without writing your own loops*:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Generate a 3D 'cube' of data
>>> data3D = np.random.uniform(0,10, 2*3*5).reshape((2,3,5))
>>> data3D
array([[[ 7.44,  1.14,  2.5 ,  3.3 ,  6.05],
        [ 1.53,  8.91,  1.63,  8.95,  2.46],
        [ 3.57,  3.29,  6.43,  8.81,  6.43]],

       [[ 4.67,  2.67,  5.29,  7.69,  7.59],
        [ 0.26,  2.88,  7.58,  3.27,  4.55],
        [ 5.84,  9.04,  7.16,  9.18,  5.68]]])

# Grab some "views" of the data
>>> front  = data3D[:,:,0]  # all rows and columns, first slice
>>> back   = data3D[:,:,-1] # all rows and cols, last slice
>>> top    = data3D[0,:,:]  # first row, all cols, all slices 
>>> bottom = data3D[-1,:,:] # last row, all cols, all slices
>>> r_side = data3D[:,-1,:] # all rows, last column, all slices
>>> l_side = data3D[:,0,:]  # all rows, first column, all slices
```

See what the front looks like:

```
>>> plt.imshow(front, interpolation='none')
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: front of data cube]

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that with `.sum()` you can quickly look at a true projection (not a slice) of the cube onto any side.  `front_proj = data3D[:, :, :].sum(axis=2)` and `top_proj = data3D[:, :, :].sum(axis=0)`, etc.

Comment: Curt, I had to add plt.show() to get the image to open onscreen

Comment: @DanPatterson, I just edited my answer to include the `plt.show()`, which is necessary if you are not running IPython in one of the "inline" modes.

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I wrote the below as a visualization aid for 3D arrays. Was also a good learning exercise.

```
# Python 2.7.10
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import *

def f_Print3dArray(a_Array):
    v_Spacing = (len(str(amax(abs(a_Array)))) + 1) if amin(a_Array)\
        < 0 else (len(str(amax(a_Array))) + 1)
    for i in a_Array[:,:,::-1].transpose(0,2,1):
        for index, j in enumerate(i):
            print(" " * (len(i) - 1 - index) + "/ ", end="")
            for k in j:
                print(str(k).ljust( v_Spacing + 1), end="")
            print("/")
        print()

a_Array = arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
print(a_Array)
print()

f_Print3dArray(a_Array)
```

Converts this:

```
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 6  7  8]]

 [[ 9 10 11]
  [12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]

 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]
  [24 25 26]]]
```

To this:

```
  / 2   5   8   /
 / 1   4   7   /
/ 0   3   6   /

  / 11  14  17  /
 / 10  13  16  /
/ 9   12  15  /

  / 20  23  26  /
 / 19  22  25  /
/ 18  21  24  /
```

Hope it helps someone.