# Reshape 2D array to 3D array along rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array of 3n rows and m columns. How do I reshape it into a 3D numpy array of n rows m columns and 3 slices along the 3rd dimension.

[image: 2D to 3D transformation rowise]

Comment: Start with a reshape to (3,n,m).  Then if you want `transpose` to (n,m,3).

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the one solution. I am sure there are other ways to do it.

```
import numpy as np
#Generate 24 element 1D array and reshape to 6 rows and 4 columns
a_Array = np.arange(24).reshape(6, 4)
#reshape to distribute data along axis 2 then axis 1 and then axis 0 in order, 
#this is what numpy reshape does by default
a_Array.reshape(2,3,4)
#Swap axes 1 and 2
a_Array.reshape(2,3,4).swapaxes(1,2)
#Transpose to arrange data with data distributed along axis 1
a_Array.reshape(2,3,4).swapaxes(1,2).T
```

[image]

[Transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034237/how-does-numpys-transpose-method-permute-the-axes-of-an-array/32034565#32034565)
[Visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008483/numpy-fastest-3d-to-2d-projection)

Link 1 helped understand arrays in multi-dimensions in general.
Link 2 was used to generate visual attached as the picture.